# Why can't I use logout method after DELETE permissions API request?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API with JS SDK

This might seem a duplicate of some other related questions, but it **ISN"T**.

Here's why:

I can use `FB.logout()` perfectly fine on click of a button on my website. There's no issue.

The issue is when I first call following API:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', function(response) {
   console.log(response); //GIVES SUCCESS
});
```

And then calling logout method as described below gives error:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
   console.log(response); //NO RESPONSE
});
```

**Error:** Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/home.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

The exact code that gives error:

```
 FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', function(response) {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log(response); //NO RESPONSE
     });
 });
```

I saw questions and solutions related to above problem and I've already added my site domain and url in Facebook app's settings. This problem occurs **only when** I delete permissions first and then logout.

I'm really stuck at this. Is this really an issue? If yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: What about this surprises you? Deleting all permissions also invalidates all existing access tokens for the user (as documented), but logging out via API requires an active user access token (as documented), so ...

Comment: I didn't knew about this. Thank you. Now I'm seeing another strange problem. Chrome on Android doesn't open the login dialogue when I login with re-request parameter. However it does work when I login and allow permissions for the first time. But doesn't work again with re-request. Chrome tries to open the popup but it doesn't open. In all other mobile browsers like Firefox, it works perfectly. Maybe browser issue?

Comment: Re-request is only for asking again for a permission the user declined before. You just removed all granted permissions, so you should ask for them again _normally_.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that. The user declined only one of them. I use re-request login to get that remaining permission. Still Chrome in android can't open popup. (I removed all permissions: Yes that's true but that's a different scenario. It happens even when user is logged in and we have public_profile (default) permission.). I think there's really an issue either with my code or with browser.

Comment: Got it! It was because currently the permissions are not approved for other users except me and I was trying with a test account which was not included in app settings :D Thank you.